# Nesting xsl:when in xsl:call-template

Tags: xslt, nested

```
<xsl:call-template name="myfield">              
                    <xsl:with-param name=A/>
                    <xsl:with-param name=B/>
                    <xsl:with-param name=C/>
                    <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(specialTest))">
                        <xsl:with-param name="TEST" select="'someFunction'"/>
                    </xsl:when>                     
                    <xsl:with-param name="D"/>              
                    <xsl:with-param name="E"/>                      
</xsl:call-template>
```

I am trying to put a xsl:when condition as when i generate this xsl stylesheet, i want the other params ABCDE to be called even if the test condition fails. However, the XSL compiler complains that xsl:if cannot be a child of xsl:call-template.

Any advice, or any comprehensive table of what can be nested and what cannot be nested for XSL?

Comment: i understand the you can put the test condition outside the call-template, but for my case my call-template has about 50+ params and hence i wanted to make my coding concise. thats why i'm looking to putting the xsl:if condition within the call-template, instead of repeating huge code chunks.

Comment: You have also another problem: There is no XPath function `starts-with()` that accepts only one argument. You need to correct this, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the W3C XSLT specification, there is a syntax summary for each element which says what other elements it may contain. For example, `xsl:choose` may only contain `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise`; `xsl:call-template` may only contain `xsl:with-param`. There are many elements (for example `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` and `xsl:if`) that contain what XSLT 2.0 calls a "sequence constructor" (XSLT 1.0 officially calls it a "template", but no-one uses the term with that meaning). A sequence constructor is a sequence of instructions, and there is a list of the XSLT elements that are classified as instructions, for example `xsl:if`, `xsl:element`, `xsl:value-of`, `xsl:comment`, etc.

So the nesting rules are there in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:when>` can only be used within a `<xsl:choose>` element - however, the only element available within `<xsl:call-template>` is `<xsl:with-param>`.

Try this (untested)...

```
<xsl:call-template name="myfield">              
  <xsl:with-param name=A/>
  <xsl:with-param name=B/>
  <xsl:with-param name=C/>
  <xsl:with-param name="TEST">
    <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(specialTest))">your value</xsl:if>
  </xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="D"/>              
  <xsl:with-param name="E"/>                      
</xsl:call-template>
```

(Also you have a leading `<xsl:if>` but a trailing `<\xsl:when>` in your example... that's not going to help.)

Comment: thx freefaller, the trailing \xsl:when is a typo...i was testing xsl:when earlier.

Comment: actually, my params actually is similar to:<xsl:with-param name="myVar" select="'functionA(this);functionB()'"/>

Comment: @bouncingHippo - I was just giving you an example of how it's possible to have conditional logic for a parameter (i.e. put it within the parameter, rather than outside it). It's down to you to implement. As Michael says, the [W3C XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) will give you everything you need, otherwise if you have access to an editor like Visual Studio, it will provide intelisense helpers